# Rspec redirect_to giving 'comparison of Array with Array field' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my rails app I am trying to do a basic test which tests that after a folder creation, the user is redirected to the folder show page. I have implemented this code and it works when I do it all through the browser however the test fails and gives me this error:

```
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to folder_path(folder)
     ArgumentError:
       comparison of Array with Array failed
```

I opened this test block in pry and this was what it also said:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
from /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:43:in `sort'
```

Anyone know why this error is occuring?
Here is the test block for reference:

```
context "with valid inputs" do
    let(:alice) { Fabricate(:user) }
    let(:folder) { Fabricate.attributes_for(:folder) }

    before do
      login_user(alice)
      post :create, folder: folder
    end

    it "redirects to the folder show page" do
      response.should redirect_to folder_path(folder)
    end
```

and the corresponding controller code:

```
  def create
    new_folder(folder_params)

    if @folder.save
      flash[:success] = "Folder Created"
      redirect_to folder_path(@folder)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "An Error occured."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you know which line break in your test and in your controller ?

Comment: @Chambeur yes its the line `response.should redirect_to folder_path(folder)`

Comment: What is the return type of `Fabricate.attributes_for(:folder)` ? Are your sure that it works fine with `folder_path` ?

Comment: @Chambeur Yeah it should because its creating an instance of a model so it should work fine (it works fine in all the other specs)

Comment: `Fabricate.attributes_for` is not creating an instance of a model but a hash of all the attributes of your model (without the id attributes). So when you pass `folder` to `folder_path`, rails is looking for the `id` of a Hash.

Comment: thanks @Chambeur that makes it so clear. Don't know what I was thinking haha

Comment: Hi @Harazzy, if the answer helped you to fix your problem, then accepting it would help other people with the same problem you encountered. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, `Fabricate.attributes_for` is not creating an instance of a model but a hash of all the attributes of your model (without the id attributes). So when you pass folder to `folder_path`, rails is looking for the id of a Hash.

Here is an way to test your redirection :

```
it "redirects to the folder show page" do
  response.should redirect_to folder_path(Folder.last)
end
```

Be sure also that the last folder is the one you want :

```
it "creates a folder" do
  Folder.last.attributes.except(:id).each do |key, value|
    folder[key].should eq(value)
  end
end
```